# Do we require context:annotation-config in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have come across two elements in the Spring MVC, `context:annotation-config` and `context:component-scan`.
For me, it looks like `context:component-scan` performs the same job as `context:annotation-config` and also registers the new beans.I don't see any valid reason or scenario where we have to use `context:annotation-config`.
Please provide some insights if it gives any additional benefits in specific scenarios for Spring MVC applications.

Comment: Don't use either in new code, and use Spring Boot with Java configuration instead.

Comment: Yes, But my question is is there is any specific use for context:annotation-config

Comment: No, It's only used to activate annotations in beans already registered.